# Can functional operations go beyond the vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For $f, g \in F^S$, is it necessary that $f+g \in F^S$.
[image]

I get that the definiton of a field requires the existence of two operations:

$$+:F \times F \to F$$
$$\times :F \times F \to F$$

This makes the proof trivial, however, the definition given in “Linear Algebra Done Right” makes me think there is something more subtle going on here.
[image]
[image]

There is no mention that the addition and scalar multiplication functions assigns an element $x+y \in F \ \forall  \ x, y \in F$, like in vector spaces. Is this a necessary condition, i.e does “along with operations of addition and scalar multiplication” imply that the elements obtained after the operations are applied on every pair still lie in the field or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, the elements obtained after addition and multiplication must lie in the same field also, i.e., a field is *closed* under the said operations. More often than not, such details are omitted since it is implicitly assumed that an algebraic structure is closed under its operations (if not, the operation is probably not worth considering.)

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the definition of fields, “along with operations of addition and [*usually not called "scalar"*] multiplication” means indeed what you wrote: $+ :F \times F \to F$ and $\times :F \times F \to F.$

Note that in the definition of an $F$-vector space $E$ (like your example $E=F^S$), addition is similarly $+:E\times E\to E,$ but *scalar* multiplication is $\cdot:F\times E\to E.$ Look at ["internal and external binary operations" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation).